# plot of a clisterprofiler does not work

Tags: r

When I plot the ggo result it works very good, but when I put the plot into an event of a button of RGtk2, it doesn't. It also doesn't show any error message so I have no idea why the plot has not drawn.
Here are the 2 codes of plotting ggo with and without a button.
First code:

```
library(clusterProfiler)
library("DOSE")
data(geneList)
gene <- names(geneList)[abs(geneList) > 2]
head(gene)
ggo <- groupGO(gene = gene,
organism = "human",
ont = "BP",
level = 3,
readable = TRUE)
print(ggo)
barplot(ggo, drop=TRUE, showCategory=12)
```

The second code using the button:

```
library(RGtk2)
win<-gtkWindow()
b<-gtkButton("ok")
win$add(b)
gSignalConnect(b,"clicked",l<-function(b){
library(clusterProfiler)
library("DOSE")
data(geneList)
gene <- names(geneList)[abs(geneList) > 2]
ggo <- groupGO(gene = gene,
organism = "human",
ont = "BP",
level = 3,
readable = TRUE)
print(ggo)
barplot(ggo, drop=TRUE, showCategory=12)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe call print explicitly.

```
print(barplot(ggo, drop=TRUE, showCategory=12))
```